# Changing the inputview property of a UITextView to nil leades tp app crash

Tags: ios, datepicker, textview, resignfirstresponder, inputview

I am trying to reopen system keyboard on dismissing date picker.
I have written code as:

```
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];
if ([self.textView.inputView isEqual:self.datePicker]) {
        //Display the keyboard
        self.textView.inputView = nil;
}
else {
        self.textView.inputView = self.datePicker;
}
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

But with this code app crashes and if I comment self.textView.inputView = nil; this line then I am not able to get back my system keyboard and dismiss date picker.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?